# Git- get all the commits where a header file was first added

Tags: git

My original task is to generate a JSON like below [Using python]-

```
{
"a.h": {
    "branch": ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
    "paths": ["a/b/c", "a/b/d"]
   }
...
...
...
}
```

So, is there any way to get all the commits where a `header file` was added so that I can get all the details associated to the commits.

Please let me know if my approach is not feasible and if there is any better way for the same.

And also, let me know if my question is unclear :).

Thanks for your time and patience!

Answer (score 0):

seems this can help me:-

```
git log --all --pretty=format:"%h" --diff-filter=A
```

doc link: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Any other better solution is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: This will output the list of hashes of all commits where *anything* was added. You'd need to add something to filter upon a path : `-- path/to/file`